# Under which assumptions are two Borel measures equal?

Tags: integration, general-topology, analysis, measure-theory

Assume $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space and $\mathcal B (X)$ the corresponding Borel $\sigma$-Algebra. Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two Borel measures on $\mathcal B (X)$. Now let $Q$ be some set of measurable functions $f : X \to \mathbb C$.

Under which (minimal) assumptions on the topology $\tau$ or the set $Q$ can we conclude that from

$$
\int_X f \, d\mu = \int_X f \, d\nu \ \ \ \ \ \forall f \in Q
$$

follows $\mu = \nu$?

Comment: You must be able to approximate every measurable set by elements in $Q$.

Comment: If $Q$ contain unitary function of open set, then $\mu=\nu$. Is it the minimal condition ? I'm not really sure.

Comment: The classical case is $X$ locally compact Hausdorff and $Q$ all continuous (real) functions. This is Riesz duality in essence.

Comment: Can we also replace the set of all continuous functions by a dense subset and still argue with Riesz?